# Type Mismatch for Workbook declaration VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Trying to values from one Workbook to another

```
Sub CopyValues()

    'Current Workbook 1
    Dim B As Worksheet: Set bun = Sheets("Workbook1Sheet1")

    'Since Workbook 2 is open
    'Getting a type mismatch error on this line, please note the workbook is open
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook: Set wkb2 = "Workbook2.xls"   


    Dim x As Integer
    x = 3
    B.Range("E" & x).Value = "=vlookup(D3,'wkb2'A!$D:$F,3,0)"

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wkb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2")`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response :)

Comment: Also I guess, the `bun` should be `B` in `Dim B As Worksheet: Set bun = Sheets("Workbook1Sheet1")`. I would recommend that you add `Option Explicit` on top of your code

Comment: I think this is what you are trying? `Dim B As Worksheet: Set B = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 4):

When you use `Set x = ....` you are setting an object.
So `Set Wkb2 = "..."` does not work because you are assigning a string.
Ambie answered your question. It works because `WorkBooks("...")` gives you an object

Answer (score 2):

Try the formula assignment as,

```
B.Range("E" & x).Formula = "=vlookup(D" & x & ", [Workbook2.xls]Sheet1!$D:$F, 3, false)"
```

Once you've assigned the second workbook with `Set wkb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xls")` you cannot use **wkb2** inside a quoted string and you need a worksheet as well as a cell range.

Answer (score 0):

```
 B.Range("E" & x).Value = "=vlookup(D3,'wkb2'A!$D:$F,3,0)"
```

With that you want it to be

```
B.Range("E"&x).Value = "=vlookup(D3,'" & wkb2 & "'A!$D:$F,3,0)"
```

Making sure wkb2 declares the workbook and the sheet also.